# Retorno de Dados JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

Estou realizando um simples retorno de dados em uma função Jquery. Porém a mensagem de erro é exibida.
Segue codigo

JSON:

```
<?php 
                 header('Content-Type: application/json');
                 $dados = "Meus Dados";
                 echo json_encode($dados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);     
?>
```

Jquery:

```
function carregarJson(){
 $.ajax({
      url: "json.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);   
      },
      error:function(){
        alert("erro");
      }   
    }); 

  }
```

Comment: Que mensagem de erro?

Comment: apenas aquele alert de "erro" é exibido

Comment: Da um `console.log(data)` em `error:function ...`

Comment: Experimente esse formato: `header('Content-Type:' . "text/plain");`

Answer (score 1):

Simples função para retorno de dados com Json

JSON:

```
<?php 
                 $dados = "Meus Dados";
                 echo json_encode($dados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);     
?>
```

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "inc/json.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(data){
        alert(data);   
      },
      error:function(){
        console.log(data);
      }   
    });
```